# How to group by in Pandas, have function with argument on all groups and return argument

Tags: python, function, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am building up experience in Pandas and have bumped into this challenge: I have a source data frame, say df_source, with columns 'A', 'B', 'C'. I want to group by 'A' and 'B', and per group have a calculation based on all values of 'C'. The result should be a new additional column 'D'.

```
def myfunc(df, par):
    {some complex calculation based on all values of df['C']}
    return [dataframe or column]

df_source['D'] = df_source.groupby(['A', 'B']).{call myfunc per group, and pass parameter value}
```

My question: how do I move from here to create a column 'D'? As I understand, *apply* works on single rows and not on groups.

**Update:** within a single group, each row may have a different value for D, e.g. a string 'i-th element/n-elements in group'.

Comment: `grouped_df.aggregate(func)` applies `func` on every grouped object.
See [pandas Group By](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). You could try concatenating these to a column and adding this to the original df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
def myfunc(x, p):
    #y => return `Series`
    return y

df_source['D'] = df_source.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x, par))
```

Another possible solution is use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df_source['D'] = df_source.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(lambda x: myfunc(x, par))
```

Comment: And if myfunc takes a second argument (a number for example)?

Comment: another parameter is some constant?

Comment: Within a single run, yes, but it should be passed explicitely.